# can't save data to database using ajax and linq

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linq

this is my `listview.aspx` file having AJAX function and listview controller. I couldn't save this data:

```
$(function () {
    var firstname = $('#fname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lanme').val();
    var education = $('#education').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'listview.aspx/Insert_data',
            data: "{ 'First' : '" + firstname + "' , 'Last' : '" + lastname + "' , 'education' : '" + education + "' , 'Email' : '" + email + "'  }",
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {                        
                $('#fname').val('');
                $('#lanme').val('');
                $('#education').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                alert('saved..');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

For the following list control:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>FirstName:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Education:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="education" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="lv1" runat="server">
     <LayoutTemplate>
         <table id="tbl1">
             <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>FirstName</th>
                 <th>LastName</th>
                 <th>Education</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
             </tr> 
             <tbody>
                 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
             </tbody>                
         </table>
     </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Id") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("First") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Last") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("education") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Email") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

And here is my method in the `listview.aspx.cs` file:

```
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    public static bool Insert_data(string fname,string lname, string edu, string email)
    {
        databaseDataContext db = new databaseDataContext();
        db.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConnect"];
        //tbl_employee tbl = new tbl_employee()
        //{
        //    First = fname,
        //    Last = lname,
        //    education = edu,
        //    Email = email
        //};
        tbl_employee tbl = new tbl_employee();
        tbl.First = @firstname;
        db.tbl_employees.InsertOnSubmit(tbl);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I submit the form for saving data, it shows an alert that says the data is saved as I wrote in the AJAX function but actually it’s not.

Comment: Does it get to your controller code?

Comment: no its not MVC structure.i am talking about ListView controller in aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing your `Insert_data` function to have the same input parameters as you are passing from the Ajax call.

Your method signature is:

```
public static bool Insert_data(string fname,string lname, string edu, string email)
```

But your Ajax call is passing:

```
data: "{ 'First' : '" + firstname + "' , 'Last' : '" + lastname + "' , 'education' : '" + education + "' , 'Email' : '" + email + "'  }",
```

You are not preventing the submit button action. Change your code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // Prevent page postback.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Ajax code here

});
```

Lastly, I prefer to pass an object, instead of lots of parameters, as it allows for easily maintainable code. You can change the string parameters you are using and replace with an object.

The object can be set in the JavaScript:

```
var mFormData = {
  FirstName: firstname,
  LastName: lastname,
  Education: education,
  Email: email
};
```

You can then pass this in through the Ajax calls data property:

```
data: JSON.stringify(mFormData)
```

Comment: still it is not happening..ajax method is not working..page is posting back.